# How can I record two simultaneous Microsoft Teams meetings, on the same computer, without audio cross interference?

Tags: audio-recording

In my new role I must simultaneously attend two Teams meetings, but  I can absolutely choose to stay silent and not speak. I plan to attend one meeting on Teams desktop App program, and the other on Microsoft Edge — both on the same laptop.

I want to avoid using another device (e.g. my phone or desktop) if possible. The issue is audio cross interference between the two meetings.

I’ve been using [Icecream Screen Recorder](https://icecreamapps.com/Screen-Recorder/) to "Capture audio." But won't this fail?

If I simply click "Capture audio" —  but people from the 2 different Teams meetings are simultaneously speaking — then their voices will cross interfere! Icecream will capture both simultaneous voices in the same recording, but won't the recording sound completely garbled and jumbled? Afterwards I must be able to listen to the speech in each meeting audibly from my recordings!

If there's no other way, then I should open one meeting on my laptop, and the other on my phone or desktop. Then I should install Icecream Recorder on each device, and record separately. Will this work?

Comment: Recording on two different devices will certainly work, and is the simplest solution. What problems do you foresee?

Comment: Audio Router and Voicemeeter Banana.  Windows 10 has Audio Router built in.  See [How to pipe both an audio file and my voice through a voice communication app?](https://superuser.com/questions/1658082/how-to-pipe-both-an-audio-file-and-my-voice-through-a-voice-communication-app/1658108#1658108)

Comment: Teams has server side recording. If your own org is hosting the meeting, or if the host allows meeting recordings, this would be much simpler and more reliable and not at all dependent on things being set up right on your own system.